# What is the lower bound for the following equation

Tags: asymptotics

f(n) = 32n^2 + 17n + 1.

The lecture slide says that lower bound can be Omega(n^2) or Omega(n).

Some body please guide me why the lower bound can be Omega (n). i know the upper bound which is O(n^2).

Zulfi.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)

Comment: Sorry I can't understand that stuff. It has very little discussion about lower bounds i.e. Omega notations.

Comment: Being a quadratic function, it is both lower and upper bounded by n^2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quadratic function; therefore $f$ is big-Theta of $n^2$. Therefore, it is both Big-O and Big-Omega of $n^2$.

However, when a function $f$ is big-Omega of another function $g$, then $f$'s growth is of greater or equal order than $g$. However, since a quadratic grows strictly faster than a linear in the long run, $n^2$ is big-Omega of $n$. Think of as if big-Omega means "greater or equal than".

Also note when $f$ is big-Omega of $g$, then $g$ is big-O of $f$. Obviously, $n$ is big-O of both $n$ and $n^2$.

Comment: "Obviously, n is big-O of both n and n2. " . This does not seem correct. Big-O notation is used for functions not for variables.

Comment: Often when referring to a function f(n) where n isnt declared we simply write f as the function. Namely f=f(n)

Comment: You are not saying 'f', you are saying 'n'  is big-O  of both 'n' and 'n^2'. I think its a typo. Please correct it, your last line.

Comment: f(n)=n, g(n)=n^2, n in O(f(n)) and O(g(n))